# Collapse whitespace of different substrings in R

Tags: r, text, twitter, gsub

I am working with Twitter data, specifically that of US politicians. When tokenizing the Tweets, I would like to keep mentions of bills and resolutions as a unigram (no n-grams). The issue is, many of these bill are entered differently by political (ex. "HR 104", "H R 104", "HR104"), there are different types of bills (ex. "HRes 1019", "S Res 18", "S Con Res 12") and the number of digits varies from 1-4 (ex. "S 1", "S 50", S 1921")

Ideally, I would want everything to be collapse into a single word with no space (ex. "HR104", SConRes18", "HJRes4525"). I am not well versed in the syntax of the gsub and grep functions, but I'm guessing that is what I would use to identify the string. I am not sure how I would collapse the spaces though.

This substring are a part of tweets, so I never have the bill on its own. For example: "The US needs immigration reform that is constitutional  protects our American interests HR 6 the American Dream and Promise Act  H R 1603 the Farm Workforce Modernization Act encourage the continuation of illegal behavior with incentivization  no repercussions 14"

And I would like to change "H R 1603" to "HR1603" in the whole text.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

Does `gsub(" ", "", x)` (where x is any string) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, fixed(" "), "")
str_replace_all(x, space(), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(x, " ")
```